# Easy Server Monitoring/Logging point in time solution?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, monitoring

I managed my company's servers and I need to know if load spiked at 3am on the web or mysql server, what processes were active in apache or what queries were going on in mysql at that point in time and maybe any other information that will help me.

I know all of that is in log files all over and its literally a PITA to look it all up and correlate data.

isnt there 1 solution thats been invented.

i know we have pingdom to monitor uptime and responsiveness.

like if it has taken 30 seconds to load a page or an error was given by apache or php or mysql to the browser, i want to know that and what mysql processes were running at the time, the apache full status and maybe top output also.

stuff like that

also would be looking for a SAAS like cloudkick, something i dont have to spend an entire month of work hours setting up when we can pay for something cheaper.

Comment: Shopping Questions are considered Off-Topic here on ServerFault.  Please see the [Help](http://serverfault.com/help) section or [Here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for more info.  **If you are interested in having a way to ask these types of questions** head over to the [IT Shopping Questions Beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59278/it-shopping-questions) and post your question as a possible question for the beta and follow the proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/)? It's able to correlate data from many sources and I personally find that their whole "log-querying/correlation paradigm" is 1,000s miles ahead of what you usually find in the log management space.

Comment: tried splunk, a bit overwhelmed by its options

Answer (score 1):

I only have experience with [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com) which I've found to have a good balance between ease of use and features. Installation is pretty easy assuming you are familiar with building from source and there is the usual learning curve to configuration it is also pretty easy to select monitoring templates to get you a large amount of monitoring data very quickly. It is also relatively easy to add custom monitoring data if needed.

I assume you have checked out the [Monitoring](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/monitoring) tag for various similar discussions.

Comment: yes checked the monitoring tag, not much there. I definitely want something that can scour my logs for me.